# Protractor - Can't expect toast notification because of error about “RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded”

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I've tried to perform expect on toast notification by the following code (please see the latest code block):

```
describe('vCita Frontage - Conversation test cases', function() {

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var currentPage = element(by.css('div.bubble-content'));
    var toast = ($("md-toast.announce.ng-scope.md-default-theme.md-bottom.d-left"));

 it('vCita New App - Conversation - Reply to existing conversation - Typing message', function() {
      browser.driver.sleep(10000);
      currentPage.isPresent().then(function (isVisible) {
         if (isVisible) {
            waitPageToLoad();
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('div.bubble-content'))), 30000);
         } else {
            browser.get('https://app.vcita.com/conversations/4oovfipphhfvvbpz');
            waitPageToLoad(); 
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('div.bubble-content'))), 30000);
         }
      });

      element(by.model('replyModel.text')).click().then(function() {
      element(by.model('replyModel.text')).sendKeys("Hello!\nHow are you?\nI'm fine thanks.\nPlease contact with me.");
    });
      browser.waitForAngular();
  });

   it('vCita New App - Conversation - Reply to existing conversation - Message sent', function() {
      element(by.css('button.green-btn.font-xs.md-button.ng-scope.md-default-theme')).click();
      browser.waitForAngular();
   });

   it('vCita New App - Conversation - Follow up', function() {
      element(by.css("button.font-xs.md-button.ng-scope.md-default-theme.gray-btn")).click();
      browser.waitForAngular();
   });

   it('vCita New App - Conversation - Follow up - Just mark for follow-up - No reminder', function() {
      var arr = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        arr.push(Math.random());
      };

      element(by.css('md-radio-button[value="no_reminder"]')).click();
      browser.waitForAngular();
      element(by.css('button[ng-click="send()"]')).click();
      browser.waitForAngular();
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.wait(function() {
        return $(toast).isDisplayed();
      }, 20000);
      // expect(toast.getText()).toContain('The card was declined.');
      browser.waitForAngular();
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
   });
```

The error has been received on the webdriver console is:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Stacktrace:

```
     RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.childCtor.base (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2163:38)
    at promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.constructor (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roa
ming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\p
romise.js:2431:23)
    at new wrappedCtr (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2366:26)
    at promise.Promise.addCallback_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:641:12)
    at promise.Promise.then (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prot
ractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:591:15)
    at Object.promise.asap (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:911:11)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:250:27
    at forEachKey (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:241:9)
    at convertKeys (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:245:5)
    at convertValue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\n
ode_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:197:16)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (C:\Users\idan
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as isDisplayed] (C:\Users\idan
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11)
    at C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\conversationTC.js:48:25
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:718:12
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
From: Task: <anonymous>
    at pollCondition (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1625:14)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1621:7
    at new promise.Promise (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:355:5)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1619:12
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
From: Task: <anonymous wait>
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.wait (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise
.js:1617:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.wait (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriv
er.js:714:21)
    at [object Object].to.(anonymous function) [as wait] (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\protractor.js:63:25)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\convers
ationTC.js:47:15)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\ja
sminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.start (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2162:8)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2503:14
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.finish (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2477:5)
    at [object Object].onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2504:10)==== asyn
c task ====
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\convers
ationTC.js:36:4)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\conversationTC.j
s:1:63)
```

**Technical info:**

Node JS(latest)

Selenium Webdriver 2.44

Jasmine JS

Protractor (latest)

Comment: Why are you making lots of `browser.driver.sleep(...);` ? If it's for waiting for computation you can try using `browser.waitForAngular();` instead. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Still doesn't work, the solution probably isn't related to the "sleep"

Comment: seems like a promise is never resolved, or take too much time. Do you know what is the failing test that make this error ?

Comment: Sure, The latest one, when it trying to expect a toast notification

Comment: IMO the problem is your jQuery selector in the wait clause. try something like this : `browser.wait(element(by.css('md-toast.announce.ng-scope.md-default-theme.md-bottom.d-left')).isPresent);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works  fine now! :) @Freezystem

Comment: Ok so I'll write the answer down there to help other people that might run into this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can use `browser.waitForAngular();` to wait for the resolve and computation of all promises instead of running `browser.driver.sleep(...);` that might not behave as you expect.

Then you can't use jQuery selectors in you script and thus should stick with protractor ones by replacing your toast variable with this :

```
var toast = element(by.css('md-toast.announce.ng-scope.md-default-theme.md-bot‌​tom.d-left');
//and later use it like 
browser.wait(toast.isPresent);
```

You can read more on that subject [here](http://docsplendid.com/tags/wait-for-element).